# Mysql Select query: Select employees that their position are both CEO and Owner

Tags: mysql

I have a below Table Diagram which consists mainly of 4 Tables, I would like to retrieve the company_name and person_name which is their position (CEO and Owner) of the same company.

1. Companies Table
2. People Table
3. Positions Table
4. Company_people table that combines the above three tables using foreign keys

[image]

Here are my Mysql Tables:

```
    #
# Structure for table "companies"
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `companies`;
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#
# Data for table "companies"
#

INSERT INTO `companies` VALUES (1,'Apple'),(2,'Microsoft'),(3,'Tesla'),(4,'SpaceX');

#
# Structure for table "company_person"
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `company_person`;
CREATE TABLE `company_person` (
  `cp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cp_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#
# Data for table "company_person"
#

INSERT INTO `company_person` VALUES (1,1,13,1),(2,1,13,2),(3,2,12,2),(4,2,12,1),(5,4,11,2),(6,4,11,1),(7,3,11,1),(8,3,11,2),(9,1,14,3),(10,2,16,3),(11,3,17,4),(12,4,20,3),(13,4,17,3),(14,2,18,3),(15,3,18,2),(16,4,17,2),(17,4,17,4),(18,1,12,2),(19,3,12,2),(20,4,12,1);

#
# Structure for table "people"
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `people`;
CREATE TABLE `people` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#
# Data for table "people"
#

INSERT INTO `people` VALUES (11,'Elon Mask'),(12,'Bill Gates'),(13,'Steve Jobs'),(14,'Azad Omer'),(15,'Johney Deep'),(16,'Brad Pitt'),(17,'Jeff'),(18,'Zukerberg'),(19,'Will Smith'),(20,'Rapar');

#
# Structure for table "position"
#

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `position`;
CREATE TABLE `position` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

#
# Data for table "position"
#

INSERT INTO `position` VALUES (1,'Owner'),(2,'CEO'),(3,'Stake Holder'),(4,'Third Party');
```

Now, I would like to retrive company_name, person_name  that are thier position are (CEO and Owner) of the same company, here are what I've tried so far:

```
SELECT
    com.name,
    p.name,
    COUNT(*)
FROM `company_person` 

INNER JOIN companies com 
ON com.id=company_id

INNER JOIN people p
ON p.id = person_id

WHERE position_id IN(1, 2) # 1=Owner, 2=CEO
GROUP BY company_id, person_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

Which Gives me a result which I belive is not accurate this query:

```
| com       | person        | COUNT(*) 
| ---       | ------        | -------- 
| Apple     | Steve Jobs    | 2 
| Microsoft | Bill Gates    | 2 
| Tesla     | Elon Mask     | 2 
| SpaceX    | Elon Mask     | 2
```

My question is, is this way the proper way?

Can you please help me out if you know another proper way which is correct and better than my way?

Comment: I wonder what's wrong with your result? inaccurate refer to what? COUNT(*) or? All your result are correct! Steve Jobs is the owner also CEO of Apple and others are correct!

Comment: Would you elaborate on `I would like to retrive company_name, person_name that are thier position are (CEO and Owner) of the same company` ?

Comment: @learning imagine if this table has millions of records, does this answer will be correct always?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand that you are wanting, there are a number of issues

1. Your primary table has **multiple entries** for the same company_id and person_id, so you have to do a distinct.
2. **Count** makes no sense at all, so I have dropped it.
3. **IN** will do an **OR** function, you want an **AND**.  I have done two sub-queries for this aliasing the company_person to a different name to avoid confusion.

So here is one simple solution to illustrate the concept.

```sql
select distinct p1.person_id, p1.company_id, com.name company, p.name person
from company_person p1
inner join companies com 
on com.id=p1.company_id
inner join people p
on p.id = p1.person_id
where p1.position_id = 1
and exists (select p2.position_id 
              from company_person p2 
              where p2.position_id = 2)
```

I have left the ids in there as it helps to build up the query before you do the joins to fetch the names.  You can remove them from the **select**.

Comment: Hello Dear Rohit, Thanks but your query doesn't fetch the right and correct result. Could you please try on your side again, it fetches all the records that are not (CEO and Owner) also

Comment: I can say it's fetchs all records inside company_person table exactly

Comment: Its a bit hard to visualize the data in a codepen.  Try this and please tick the answer if it works.